# Why typing incorrect password shows incorrect login error?

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have used `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth` to install authentication in my app. When I type right login, wrong password and submit my login form, the login input lights red as invalid and invalid login message is showing and zero information about wrong password. Have you any idea, why it happens?

That's my form, I can provide any other part of code, but I don't know, where should I look for mistakes.

```
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" class="mt-4">
            @csrf
        
            <div class="form-group row">
        
                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                    <input placeholder="{{ __('Login') }}" id="login" type="text" class="form-control @error('login') is-invalid @enderror" name="login" value="{{ old('login') }}" required autocomplete="login" autofocus>
        
                    @error('login')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            @php dump($errors); @endphp
                        </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-group row">
        
                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                    <input placeholder="{{ __('auth.Password') }}" id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">
        
                    @error('password')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
        
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                            {{ __('auth.Remember Me') }}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 text-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                        {{ __('auth.Log in') }}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
   </form>
```

Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'login';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the password is correctly formatted.

If you type an empty password, you will see the password formatting validation trigger.

---

If you look at the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait, you will see the following code.

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ]);
    }
```

When authentication fails (look-up in the database), this will send back a validation exception on the username key.

Comment: You're right! So I guess I should divide somewhere validation for login and validation for password, if I want to show "Invalid password message"?

Comment: @Kida Yes, but I do not suggest it. This will allow anyone to log in with an email address and be told if that email uses your service. This could be considered a security breach.

Comment: Okay, thanks, so maybe I will consider to not do that. Anyway, when I type no password, the message "The password field is required." is showing. I'm wondering now, when the message "The provided password is incorrect." will show? Cause I see in `resources\lang` directory that this kind of message exists too.

Comment: @Kida It is because the frontend HTML input field has a "required" attribute - this will make the browser show you that the field is required before even sending it to the backend. If the browser doesn't respect this or haven't implemented it, it will reach the backend, and the backend will throw that error. (You can try to remove "required" on the input field and try to submit again.)

Comment: I meant, that I'm getting backend error "The password field is required." (even without required attribute in HTML) and I was wondering when backend would throw me message that password is incorrect. I found that it may be used in `confirm.blade.php`. And `reset.blade.php` is using "The password confirmation does not match." message. Now all is more clear for me, thanks a lot!